# How to use FFmpeg to record multiple screens on MacOS？

Tags: ffmpeg

I wanted to record multiple screens simultaneously on MacOS and store them in a video file.Same as the screenshot below.
[image]

I found a command to do this, but need to know the size of each screen.

```
ffmpeg \
-f avfoundation -pix_fmt uyvy422 -i 1 \
-f avfoundation -pix_fmt uyvy422 -i 2 \
-pix_fmt yuv420p -r 30 -preset ultrafast -b:v 5000k -t 15 \
  -filter_complex \
    "nullsrc=size=3286x1080 [background]; \
    [0:v] setpts=PTS-STARTPTS [left]; \
    [1:v] setpts=PTS-STARTPTS [right]; \
    [background][left] overlay=shortest=1 [background+left]; \
    [background+left][right] overlay=shortest=1:x=1366 [left+right]" \
  -map [left+right] out.mp4 -y
```

Is there a way to record a screen without knowing the size of each screen?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do it using the new [xstack](http://ffmpeg.org/ffmpeg-filters.html#xstack) filter.

Use

```
ffmpeg \
-f avfoundation -pix_fmt uyvy422 -i 1 \
-f avfoundation -pix_fmt uyvy422 -i 2 \
-filter_complex \
    [0:v] setpts=PTS-STARTPTS [left]; \
    [1:v] setpts=PTS-STARTPTS [right]; \
    [left][right] xstack=inputs=2:layout=0_0|w0_0 [left+right]" \
  -map [left+right] -pix_fmt yuv420p -r 30 -preset ultrafast -b:v 5000k -t 15 \ out.mp4 -y
```

Get the latest dated build from https://ffmpeg.zeranoe.com/builds/macos64/static/

Comment: Thank you very much. It's very useful to me

Comment: After correcting the missing starting brace, I tried following command

./ffmpeg -f avfoundation -pix_fmt uyvy422 -i 1 -f avfoundation -pix_fmt uyvy422 -i 2 -filter_complex "[0:v] setpts=PTS-STARTPTS [left]; [1:v] setpts=PTS-STARTPTS [right]; [left][right] xstack=inputs=2:layout=0_0|w0_0 [left+right]" -map [left+right] -pix_fmt yuv420p -r 30 -preset ultrafast -b:v 5000k -t 15 out.mp4 -y

Comment: After correcting a missing bracket, I ran the command and its giving 

"no matches found: [left+right]"

What could be wrong?

Comment: You should also escape the `[left+right]`. This is working command:

`ffmpeg -f avfoundation -pix_fmt uyvy422 -i 1 -f avfoundation -pix_fmt uyvy422 -i 2 -filter_complex "[0:v] setpts=PTS-STARTPTS [left]; [1:v] setpts=PTS-STARTPTS [right]; [left][right] xstack=inputs=2:layout=0_0|w0_0 [left+right]" -map '[left+right]' -pix_fmt yuv420p -r 30 -preset ultrafast -b:v 5000k -t 15 out.mp4 -y`

Comment: Yes, on shells where [ and ] are meta-characters, like bash.